# Html Heat Map Based On Value

Tags: javascript, jsp, colors, cell, heatmap

i have a table which is created dynamically from database.

```
            for (int m = 0; m < table.size(); m++) {

                out.print("<tr>");

                for (int k = 0; k < table.get(0).length; k++)

                {    out.print("<td width='10'>");
                     out.print(table.get(m)[k]);
                     out.println("</td>");
                }
                out.println("</tr>");

            }
```

I want to make a each cell coloured based on its value , The out put of my table is ;

[image: My image]

Comment: You can run a script just after the table is made, to check for values and update styles (There probably must be a better way though)

Comment: Do you have any sample ? I couldnt imagine @ArmaGeddON

Comment: You can iterate though all td elements you want to change, check their value and change style accordingly

Comment: @mstfky Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [HSL](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) instead of [RGB](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp) to represent your colors.

You will need something like this:

```js
let table = '<table>';

for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

  table += '<tr>';

  for(let k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
    const value = Math.random();
    const h = 240 - value * 240;
    
    table += '<td style="background: hsl(' + h + ', 100%, 50%)">' + value.toFixed(2) + '</td>';
  }

  table += '</tr>';
}

document.write(table);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  color: #000;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

Ideally, add the `style` attributes in your backend so that the page that you send to the client already has the colors. If for any reason you can't do that, then just go over the cells in the client, reading their values and adding them the appropriated background color.

Using the other components of HSL you could generate different colors schemas. For example, a single-hue scale, with black and white on its ends and a colors of your choice in the middle, blue in this case:

```js
let table = '<table>';

for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

  table += '<tr>';

  for(let k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
    const value = Math.random();
    const l = value * 100;
    const textColor = l < 35 ? '#FFF' : '#000';
    
    table += '<td style="background: hsl(200, 100%, ' + l + '%); color: ' + textColor + '">' + value.toFixed(2) + '</td>';
  }

  table += '</tr>';
}

document.write(table);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  color: #000;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```